# STM32 F334R8 I2C GPIO problem - not working

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I have a Nucleo-F334R8 and am using STM32Cube IDE Version: 1.3.0 Build: 5720_20200220_1053 (UTC).
The UART2 already works and prints stuff correctly, now I want to control a display over I2C, but the Nucleo seems to have trouble to initialize the GPIOs for the I2C interface.

I configured the IOC file to enable the I2C and the UART2 interface. I change no properties of the I2C interface, just enabled it. It compiles succefully, but when I try to let it run, it says in the debug console that it doesn't respond anymore. I debugged it to see where it stops working. Its the line, where it initializes the GPIOs for the I2C interface (PA14, PA15).

```
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

In this Method it stops here:

```
/* Configure Alternate function mapped with the current IO */
    temp = GPIOx->AFR[position >> 3u];
    temp &= ~(0xFu << ((position & 0x07u) * 4u));
    temp |= ((GPIO_Init->Alternate) << ((position & 0x07u) * 4u));
    GPIOx->AFR[position >> 3u] = temp;
```

With these variables set:
[image]

I dont know what to do, to make it work. Does anyone know how?

A strange thing I noticed:
When the program doesnt respond anymore and I try to debug it again, it doesn't find a target on the device. Even if I disable the I2C again, it doesn't find a target on the device. So I created a new project, where I only enabled UART2, and let it debug. This time it debugs successfully without an error message. Then I tried to upload the other project again, where I disabled the I2C, and this time it runs successfully. When I try to let it run with I2C enabled, it still doesn't work and doesnt respond anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the Solution was fairly simple. You just have to connect the I2C SDA and SCL datalines to the different pins (PA14 was used for JTAG clock). According to the Manual PB9(sda) and PB8(scl) should be used.

Comment: It is not the answer. The question is not about programming. It is a trivial truth - you need to read the documentation. **"MAGIC** functions and libraries will not save you from knowing your hardware